# AngularJS API call inside getter function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I've inherited a project in AngularJS with some structural issues. It uses an API call to fetch some settings from an endpoint but sometimes the application attempts to use these settings before they're loaded resulting in an 'undefined' error.

I attempted to solve this by using a getter. The idea was that when some method accesses the settings object, it would check if they were already loaded in and if not, fetch them from the API.

I've got it working after a while but there's a problem with this idea. When multiple methods access the settings at the same time (when loading the page) the API is being called multiple times because the first call hasn't come back to override the internal `_settings` yet.

```
    vm._settings  = null;
    Object.defineProperty(vm,'settings',{get: function(){
      if(vm._settings == null){
        settings_service.get().$promise.then(function success(response) {
          vm._settings = response;
          console.log(vm._settings);
          console.log("returning in");
          return vm._settings;
        }, function error(err) {
          handle_api_error(ngNotify, err);
        });  
      }
      else return vm._settings;
    }});
```

I can't figure out a way to let the other attempts to execute the getter wait until the first call returns and use that result instead. I'm not sure if I should use await, promises or something else. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You want to debounce these requests. You could use an existing library or just implement your own.

```
app.factory('debounce', function($timeout) {
    return function(callback, interval) {
        var timeout = null;
        return function() {
            $timeout.cancel(timeout);
            timeout = $timeout(function () { 
                callback.apply(this, args); 
            }, interval);
        };
    }; 
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. [ng-debounce-throttle](https://github.com/Brakebein/ng-debounce-throttle) was already being used somewhere else so I've decided to go with that one. It stops the flood of API calls as expected but the settings object now returns undefined again so i'm kind of confused. `var something = crtl.settings.something` says it can't read something from undefined. Is the debounce not supposed to support this?

Comment: The issue seems to be that `this` is undefined. I'll see if I can pass the correct context manually inside the debounce function.